# Lg Webos TV project Parameter passing or message passing after a botton click

Tags: javascript, json

I am new in Lg Webos tv. I am stuck in a webos tv project.

I need to send messages that coming from command prompt or CLI launcher or some parameter from a notification button. I need help - any sample project of this will be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

The webOS engine support several stuff,
[image: web engine | https://developer.lge.com/webOSTV/develop/web-app/webos-tv-platform/web-engine/]

[Web Engine link](https://developer.lge.com/webOSTV/develop/web-app/webos-tv-platform/web-engine/)

And then you can see the default [Luna Service API](https://developer.lge.com/webOSTV/api/webos-service-api/) to do your project. If the messages you need to be send when the app on tv is open the above can work. If the app needs to be closed at tv then you need a [JS service](https://developer.lge.com/webOSTV/develop/js-services/) for this to happen.

And finally you can read the messages at least from TV side with the one of the supported web engine technologies that webOS allows.